# Unable to add Game Center achievement and leaderboard: Lightbox Save Failure: Failed to takeValuesFromRequest => null

Tags: app-store-connect, game-center, achievements

After adding all information (Language, Title, Pre-earned Description, Earned Description, Image) for a Language in iTunes connect for an achievement, and clicking Save, I get this message in a popup

> Lightbox Save Failure: Failed to takeValuesFromRequest => null

I am unable to save the Language. Thus unable to add any achievement at all since they need Language.

Anyone got the same issue? Related to the current iOS Dev Center downage?

Thinking this is a browser issue (iTunes connect sometimes just doesn't work well outside of Safari), I also tried Safari as well as the initial Google Chrome. No luck. Same error.

Comment: I now got the same error when trying to save a leaderboard Language resulting in impossibility to add leaderboards too. Things are looking dark at sites of Apple. :-(

Comment: I just had the same problem trying to create a new issue in apple's newstand

Comment: Oh looks like they don't want any more issues ;-)

Comment: I have a feeling that this has something to do with the prolonged downtime in Developer centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back this morning, I successfully added a new Leaderboard. I guess the bug might be fixed now.

Comment: Same with Newsstand. Fixed now.